# R function min return class changed from posixct to numeric when first argument is NULL

Tags: r

I want to find the first date in several dataframecolumns (class POSIXct), some of which may be empty, and I found that min() sometimes casts this to numeric.

So I started investigating when this happens, and found out it happens if the first argument happens to be NULL (it doesn't matter if any of the other input is NULL).

Compare the following examples:

```
min(as.POSIXct(c('2018-01-01','2018-01-02'), tz='UTC')) # Works as expected
min(as.POSIXct(c('2018-01-01','2018-01-02'), tz='UTC'), NULL) # Still fine
min(NULL, as.POSIXct(c('2018-01-01','2018-01-02'), tz='UTC')) # Returns 1514764800
```

Is this a bug?

Right now I've created a workaround like this:

```
min(if(is.null(df$timest1)) as.POSIXct('2099-12-31') else df$timest1,
    df$timest2, df$timest3)
```

But this seems ugly at best, I expected min() to ignore any NULLs

Any thoughts on whether I'm doing something wrong, or should I file a bug report?

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong if `df$timest1` can be either `NULL` or not when running your script/function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min` is an S3 generic, see `help("min")`:

> max and min are generic functions: methods can be defined for them
>   individually or via the Summary group generic.

```
methods(min)
#no methods found
methods(Summary)
#[1] Summary.data.frame      Summary.Date            Summary.difftime        Summary.factor          Summary.numeric_version
#[6] Summary.ordered         Summary.POSIXct         Summary.POSIXlt        
#see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

This shows that the `POSIXct` method is defined via the group generic. Now, S3 dispatch always considers the class of the first parameter only (otherwise you need S4).

```
class(NULL)
#[1] "NULL"
```

There is no `min` method for class `"NULL"`. Thus the default method is used. The documentation says:

> For historical reasons, NULL is accepted as equivalent to integer(0).

```
class(c(integer(0), as.POSIXct(c('2018-01-01','2018-01-02'), tz='UTC')))
#[1] "numeric"
class(min(NULL, as.POSIXct(c('2018-01-01','2018-01-02'), tz='UTC')))
#[1] "numeric"
```

So, this is all as documented. There is no bug.